# How to access CF developer edition server on Parallels VM from OS X

Tags: macos, windows-xp, virtualbox, parallels, coldfusion

I have a Windows XP system with CF8 development edition setup on a Parallels VM on my OS X machine that I use for development.

CF8 is using the built-in webserver, so I access my development sites on this VM on `localhost:8500`.

So, I would like to be able to access the localhost of my VM from OSX, so that I can test my development sites on Safari, and the iOS simulator without having to install CF8 on OSX.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you set up networking (if you want to share that web server to your local network, *bridged* networking is probably the recommended option).

Generally, your VM has its own IP address assigned by the Parallels network adapter. Find it out through the `ipconfig` command (ran under `cmd`) in your Windows installation or by looking at the connection's details. Don't forget to disable the firewall.

Also, I don't know about CF development server, but if it has an option only to allow local connections, disable this as well, since the requests from your host will seem to come from another machine.

In OS X, open up Safari, enter the IP address and the port of your Windows machine in the address bar.

---

Related Stack Overflow questions:

- [Access Parallels Windows localhost from Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673595/access-parallels-windows-localhost-from-mac)
- [Access to a server on a Parallels VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166196/access-to-a-server-on-a-parallels-vm)
- [Running a server in Parallels virtual machine. Is it possible for the host to access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970442/running-a-server-in-parallels-virtual-machine-is-it-possible-for-the-host-to-acc)

Comment: I use this method (along with custom DNS entries in my HOSTS file) all day long, and have for several years. Definitely works well.

Comment: @DanShort So there's no specific configuration to make in CF server?

Comment: Nope, just remember that as far as your Mac and Windows are concerned, they're different computers. Parallels is just a go-between, and you need to treat the Windows box as if it's a machine sitting on the other side of your house, not on the same hard drive as OSX.